# Template function specialization for specific interface

Tags: c++, templates

I have the following piece of code:

```
class ICookable
{
public:
    virtual void CookMe () = 0;
    virtual ~ICookable () {};
};

class Egg : public ICookable
{
public:
    virtual void CookMe () {cout << "Egg cooked!" << endl;}
};

template <class T>
void Cook (T&)
{
    cout << "Item Uncookable!" << endl;
}

template <>
void Cook (ICookable& c)
{
    c.CookMe ();
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    Egg egg;
    Cook (egg);
    return 0;
}
```

I want the Cook function to behave differently depending on whether its parameter is inherited from ICookable interface or not.
However in the example above I get "Item Uncookable" message for Egg parameter, unless I manually write:

```
Cook<ICookable> (egg);
```

Is there a way to let the compiler automatically choose the right realization for ICookable descendants?

Comment: There's something terribly wrong with this code, and I can't find it. Even if you overload cook for ICookable, which should be selected every time, it doesn't work.

Comment: @DeadMG: Why should it be selected every time?  Reading "for some argument j, ICSj(F1) is a better conversion sequence than ICSj(F2), or, if not that," [13.3.3/1, 0x FCD]—which supersedes the later "F1 is a non-template and F2 is a function template specialization"—tells me otherwise.  (But I freely admit overload resolution is horribly complex and I may very well be wrong.)

Comment: Please please please make a reflex of adding a virtual destructor to `ICookable`. This hurts my eyes (and should hurt yours).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Compile-time dispatch through [boost::is_base_of](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/libs/type_traits/doc/html/boost_typetraits/reference/is_base_of.html) and class template partial specialization:

```
template<class T, class _>
struct CookDetail {
  static void cook(T& obj) {
    cout << "uncookable\n";
  }
};
template<class T>
struct CookDetail<T, boost::true_type> {
  static void cook(ICookable& obj) {
    obj.CookMe();
  }
};

template<class T>
void cook(T& obj) {
  return CookDetail<T, boost::is_base_of<ICookable, T> >::cook(obj);
}
```

However, having cook(non_icookable_obj) "work" is an error to me.  I'd prefer the compile-time error for trying to cook a non-cookable.

Note that what you tried fails because that's just how function resolution works.  An exact match through a template (cook<Egg>(Egg&)) is considered better than one which requires a conversion (cook(ICookable&)).  Details are in the [FCD](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2010/n3092.pdf) if you want the arcane technicalities.